# Passing Empty array parameter to MockHttpServletRequestBuilder param method

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc, http-request

I am using MockHttpServletRequestBuilder to create my request for testing my framework. One of the request parameters I have is a string array. For my testing I want to test with passing an empty array in my request. However, the assertion in MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.addToMultiValueMap doesn't let me to pass null or empty values.

This is the error body I am getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'values' must not be empty
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:214)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.addToMultiValueMap(MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.java:698)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.param(MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.java:153)
at MyMockApiRequests.queryPath(MockJdbcApiRequests.java:105)
```

Is there any other way to test this condition?

Comment: You probably simply need to avoid passing the parameter if the array is empty, then there should be no parameter with that name in the query string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think setting your value to an empty string works.

My Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/config", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<TdConfig> getTdConfigs(@RequestParam(required = false) List<String> names) {
    return tdAdminService.getTdConfigs(names);
}
```

My Mockito

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    params.add("names", "");
    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = get("/admin/config")
            .params(params)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    mockMvc.perform(request)
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
            .andDo(print());
```

Printout of Request:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /admin/config
       Parameters = {names=[]}
          Headers = {Accept=[application/json]}
```